# ANYONE CAN TELL ME THAT WHY THIS CODE IS GIVING ME AN ERROR OF TABLE OT CLUSTER KEY WORD IS MISSING?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c_CUR IS
SELECT id, table_name, is_deleted   FROM  truncate_table  WHERE IS_DELETED=1   
ORDER BY id DESC;
BEGIN
FOR C IN c_CUR  LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE'|| C.table_name;
END LOOP;
END;
```

I HAVE AN ERROR TABLE OR CLUSTER KEYWORD IS MISSING

Comment: Very low quality. Lower char size and improve code style.

Comment: STOP SHOUTING! And your concatenation results in a string in which there's no space between the keyword `TABLE` and the table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very clear that you are not creating a dynamic query properly. Space is missing between `TABLE'|| C.table_name`

It must be something like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE '|| C.table_name; -- see space after TABLE
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply the error is gone and now it is saying that table or view does not exist? but when i run the cursor query then the record is showing the table!

Comment: I think this error message is pretty clear. You must check your table: `truncate_table` as it contains one or more entry with the table name which is not present in your DB.

Comment: You must accept this answer so that this question is marked as resolved